# Center Of Mass Algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, glsl

I am implementing a simple center of mass/centroid algorithm for 2D rasters. This is rather trivial on the CPU but has proven difficult to port to the GPU.
My CPU version is something like:

```
float sumX = 0., sumY = 0., c = 0.
for y in imageH:
    for x in imageW:
        if image[x, y] > threshold:
            sumX += x
            sumY += y
            c += 1.
 Point2D centroid = Point2D( sumX / c, sumY / c )
```

My GPU version (GLSL with backbuffers/Ping Pong) that currently does not work and basically should sum neighbor pixels if they meet the condition (the input texture could have a bitmask image consisting of black and white shapes, for now one shape would suffice and I will start from there).

```
vec2 pixSize = 1. / resolution;

vec4 originalTexture = texture( myTex, uv );

if( frame == 0 && originalTex.r > treshold )
{

    gl_FragColor = vec4( gl_FragCoord, 0., 0. );

else
{

    for( int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y )
    for( int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x )
    {

        vec4 data = texture( backbuffer, uv + pixSize * vec2( x, y );
        if( originalTexture.r > threshold )
        {

            sumCoord += data.xy;
            counter += 1.;
   
         }

    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4( sumCoord / counter, 0., 0. );

}
```

EDIT: On second thoughts I see that I am not adding the current fragCoord after the first frame so that is something I must take into account.

Comment: for single ROI/object mask render single pixel and in fragment loop through entire texture summing as you do ... beware texture coordinates are from 0 to 1 instead of from -1 to +1 !!! Also your current loops are hitting only 9 texels instead of the whole texture ... the increment will be `1.0/(texture_resolution-1.0)` for multiple objects you could implement object index ... and sum up only specified indexes (so one pixel per object rendering). Do you have any sample input/output ?

Comment: Thanks @Spektre I am in fact doing the uv + pixelSize * vec2( x, y ) * float( frame ) just wrote this on my phone. I am actually looking at a way of adding something like this to a JFA implementation, but decided to test a simple center of mass that only takes into account one ROI and work my way up.

Comment: I added answer with working example for this ....

Answer (score 3):

This is a straight-forward reduction problem.

Create a three-channel texture T with the values

```
if(image[x,y] > threshold) {
    T[x,y,0] = x;
    T[x,y,1] = y;
    T[x,y,2] = 1;
} else {
    T[x,y,0] = T[x,y,1] = T[x,y,2] = 0;
}
```

Then reduce the texture by a constant factor till you get a single 1x1 pixel. This takes `O(log(max(w,h)))` GPU friendly steps, thus is extremely efficient. Here are some slides about [how to do reduction on GPU](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eamenta/f15/amenta-reduce-scan-sort.pdf). In fact even something like `glGenerateMipmap()` will work, though the exact filter it uses is implementation-specefic.

Next, after you reduced the texture to a single pixel, you extract the center of mass by

```
x = T[0,0,0]/T[0,0,2];
y = T[0,0,1]/T[0,0,2];
```

Done.

**EDIT:** a simple factor-two reduction with a fragment shader can be done as simple as follows:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D TEX;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = 2*gl_FragCoord.xy/textureSize(TEX, 0);
    gl_FragColor = texture(TEX, uv);
}
```

You need to bind the previous texture to TEX with a bilinear minification filter and (0,0,0,0) clamp-to-border wrapping mode. Setup the next texture layer as the render target.

Answer (score 1):

1. **render ROI 2D texture with unique color for each object**
2. **for each object (unique color) render pixel at specified location**

   Using GLSL shaders compute the CoM for all pixels with the "same" color.
3. **`glReadPixels` at specified locations for each object**
4. **convert color back to 2D position**

**Here naive GLSL implementation of mine I just busted for fun:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
layout(location=0) in vec4 vertex;
layout(location=3) in vec4 color;
flat out vec4 col;          // object color
uniform mat4 mvp;       // texture resolution
void main()
    {
    col=color;
    gl_Position=mvp*vertex;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**CPU sise C++/OpenGL/VCL code:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Fragment
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
flat in vec4 col;       // object color
out vec4 gl_FragColor;  // fragment output color
uniform sampler2D txr;  // texture to blur
uniform float xs,ys;    // texture resolution
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    float x,y,dx,dy,xx,yy,nn;
    vec3 dc;
    dx=1.0/(xs-1.0); xx=0.0;
    dy=1.0/(ys-1.0); yy=0.0; nn=0.0;
    for (x=0.0;x<=1.0;x+=dx)
     for (y=0.0;y<=1.0;y+=dy)
      if (length(texture(txr,vec2(x,y)).rgb-col.rgb)<0.05)
       { xx+=x; yy+=y; nn++; }
    if (nn!=0){ xx/=nn; yy/=nn; }
    gl_FragColor=vec4(xx,yy,1.0,1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
GLuint  txr_img;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _obj
    {
    DWORD col;  // color
    int x,y;    // CoM
    };
const int _max_objs=32;
_obj obj[_max_objs];
int objs=0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.0,-1.0,0.0);
    glScalef(2.0/xs,2.0/ys,1.0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txr_img);

    // compute CoM using GLSL
    float m[16];
    int i,x,y,r;
    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"txr" ),0);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"xs"  ),xs);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"ys"  ),ys);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"mvp" ),1,false,m);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (x=0,y=0,i=0;i<objs;i++,x++)
        {
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&(obj[i].col));
        glVertex2i(x,y);
        }
    glEnd();
    glUseProgram(0);
    glFlush();

    // obtain data
    DWORD dat[_max_objs];
    glReadPixels(0,0,_max_objs,1,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dat);
    for (i=0;i<objs;i++)
        {
        obj[i].x=(xs*(    ((dat[i]>>16)&255)))>>8;
        obj[i].y=(ys*(255-((dat[i]>> 8)&255)))>>8;
        }

    // render image (old API)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0); glVertex2i( 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0); glVertex2i( 0,ys);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0); glVertex2i(xs,ys);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0); glVertex2i(xs, 0);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // render computed CoM
    r=10;
    glLineWidth(5.0);
    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0;i<objs;i++)
        {
        x=obj[i].x;
        y=obj[i].y;
        glVertex2i(x-r,y-r);
        glVertex2i(x+r,y+r);
        glVertex2i(x-r,y+r);
        glVertex2i(x+r,y-r);
        }
    glEnd();
    r=9;
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0;i<objs;i++)
        {
        x=obj[i].x;
        y=obj[i].y;
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&obj[i].col);
        glVertex2i(x-r,y-r);
        glVertex2i(x+r,y+r);
        glVertex2i(x-r,y+r);
        glVertex2i(x+r,y-r);
        }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);

    // textures
    Byte q;
    unsigned int *pp;
    int i,xs,ys,x,y,adr,*txr;
    union { unsigned int c32; Byte db[4]; } c;
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;   // new bmp

    objs=0;

    // image texture
    bmp->LoadFromFile("texture.bmp");   // load from file
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;      // allow direct access to pixels
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;   // set pixel to 32bit so int is the same size as pixel
    xs=bmp->Width;              // resolution should be power of 2
    ys=bmp->Height;
    txr=new int[xs*ys];         // create linear framebuffer
    for(adr=0,y=0;y<ys;y++)
        {
        pp=(unsigned int*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
        for(x=0;x<xs;x++,adr++)
            {
            // rgb2bgr and copy bmp -> txr[]
            c.c32=pp[x]; c.db[3]=0;
            q      =c.db[2];
            c.db[2]=c.db[0];
            c.db[0]=q;
            txr[adr]=c.c32;
            for (i=0;i<objs;i++)
             if (obj[i].col==c.c32)
              { i=-1; break; }
            if (i>=0)
                {
                obj[objs].col=c.c32;
                obj[objs].x=0;
                obj[objs].y=0;
                objs++;
                }
            }
        }
    glGenTextures(1,&txr_img);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    // copy it to gfx card
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txr_img);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
//  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, xs, ys, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txr);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    delete[] txr;
    delete bmp;

    int hnd,siz; char vertex[4096],fragment[4096];
    hnd=FileOpen("center_of_mass.glsl_vert",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,vertex  ,siz); vertex  [siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=FileOpen("center_of_mass.glsl_frag",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,fragment,siz); fragment[siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    glsl_init(vertex,NULL,fragment); // old version of gl_simple is without the NULL !!!
    hnd=FileCreate("GLSL.txt"); FileWrite(hnd,glsl_log,glsl_logs); FileClose(hnd);

    ClientWidth=xs;
    ClientHeight=ys;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    glDeleteTextures(1,&txr_img);
    gl_exit();
    glsl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

it uses [gl_simple.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

**This is input ROI texture:**

[image: input]

**And output:**

[image: output]

for better precision you can use more pixels per single object output, or use framebuffer with more than 8bit per channel ...